# Activity stream in angular or rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails/angular app where users can add movies to their watchlist, users can also create friendships with other users. Now I would like to create a activity stream that notifies users when a friend has added a movie to their watchlist. But I can't find any good resources on how to get started on this feature.

For the friendships I have a friendship model,

```
create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "friend_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

What would be the connection between users, friends and newly added records (movies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem. I believe you find it usefull and the documentation provides almost every case you describe.

You have one screencast on the subject [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity) and it supports both Rails 3.x and 4.x.

About your model, I believe you should start first by creating an relational model of your data and then translate it to Rails relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You can try
[Paper trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)

Any time a change is made in your system, [paper trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) can track the user id via a `whodunnit property`. This is set automatically if your controller makes a `current_user` object available. .  it will also track any user, regardless of whether there is an actual relationship between the user and the model.

https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity. It's pretty simple to install and setup.

Also there is [Audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited)

PaperTrail, [Vestal versions](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions) and [Acts as versioned](https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned) are all very powerful versioning gem. Yes, you can also use it to audit/track users' activities , but it's not very straight forward because they are 'versioning tools', but not for the 'auditing purpose'

[Userstamp](https://github.com/delynn/userstamp) and [audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) are for auditing purposing only. but Userstamp is for older Rails versions ( it's a plugin... which is not supported by Rails3(or 3.1, 3.2?) anymore )

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. I just found this as well http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity?autoplay=true